# Django Rest Framework default_authentication_classes setting

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework (3.11) with Django (3.0).

I have successfully implemented JWT authentication for my API. In the settings.py file, I have the following:

```
# Rest framework configuration
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Removing `'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',` results in the following error when hitting any of the endpoints in the API:

```
TypeError at /
'type' object is not iterable
```

The [full traceback](https://pastebin.fun/qNMqypwygW)

Does this mean the BasicAuthentication class is required for the application to run? Or is this not normal and I have a configured something incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: It would be more useful if you can show the full traceback.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, and definitely should not result in the shared exception when removed. Is removing that the only change you're doing? can you also share a sample request to the api?

Comment: Apologies, this seems to now work as expected...although I can't explain why it wasn't working previously.

Comment: looking at the tracaback, could be that a comma was missing at the end of the single item on DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES, resulting in the setting value being a single item instead of a tuple with a single item

Comment: @OzgurAkcali yes, I was confused by this initially and omitted it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely because when you removing `BasicAuthentication`, if you or formatter also remove comma at the end of `JWTAuthentication`, then python consider that as a type object, instead of collection of type objects, hence iterator fails.